# Pandas dataframe - Removing repeated/duplicate column in dataframe but keep the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe that have duplicate column name, I want to remove the remove the repeated column but I need to keep the values.

[image]

I want to remove the C and D column at the end but move the values on the same row in the first C and D column.

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Tried this code but it remove the duplicate column and keeping the first but it also remove the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

*make minimal and reproducible example for answer*

```
data = [[0, 1, 2, 3, None, None], 
        [1, None, 3, None, 2, 4], 
        [2, 3, 4, 5, None, None]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('ABCDBD'))
```

`df`

```
    A   B   C   D   B   D
0   0   1.0 2   3.0 NaN NaN
1   1   NaN 3   NaN 2.0 4.0
2   2   3.0 4   5.0 NaN NaN
```

---

**Code**

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()
```

result:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0
1   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
2   2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
```